# How to generate code coverage data in Bamboo for Angular projects?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, continuous-integration, code-coverage, bamboo

I am trying to populate code coverage for one of my projects in Bamboo. As per atlassian documents we can get code coverage using inbuilt clover plugin available with Bamboo. But unfortunately it is not showing any code coverage information. Anyone already integrated this feature for Angular projects?

Note: Build is generated using default angular-cli and test results are generated by default Karma test runner and Istanbul reporter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Angular project will not provide Clover test results "out of the box".  Instead you will have to make some project modifications and install some additional packages.  I accomplished this by doing the following:

1. Install ChromeHeadless on the Bamboo server
2. Modify `package.json` to include the following script (under scripts):

```
"test": "ng test --code-coverage --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
```

3. Create an npm task with the command `run test` in your project directory
4. Modify [karma.js](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html) to suite your needs.  I had to modify the outputDir, outputFile, and change the reporters to junit.  I also added the following lines:

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: ['json-summary', 'lcovonly', 'clover'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
```

5. Make sure the `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` and `karma-junit-reporter` are installed and present in the package.json file ([link to npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-junit-reporter)).
6. Add a JUnit Parser task in Bamboo that gets the results from `**/coverage/junit.xml`

Comment: Would like to add 2 cents. I followed all above steps and got no .xnl file generated. Piece I was missing is that junitReporter should also be configured in karma.conf.js. Consult project git hub readme file. This is basic configuration to generate .xml file with test results:

`
junitReporter: {
      outputDir: './coverage/my-project',
      outputFile: 'junit-test-results.xml',
      suite: '',
      useBrowserName: false
 }
`